# yacas factorize polynoms

Tags: polynomials, computer-science, factoring

I want factorize polynoms with [yacas](http://yacas.sourceforge.net/homepage.html) but I can do it only with univarial. E.g. I want $x^2-y^2$ factorize to $(x-y)(x+y)$. How can I do it?

Or if anybody has any suggestion to another simple, free (BSD, GPL, etc.) CAS (I need some basic things for my students, in a high school), it's acceptable for me (would be nice LaTeX output, run on console without Xorg (because it's on a server)).

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Tried http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor+x%5E2-y%5E2 ?

Comment: I know about some online CAS, but I want create a simple-to-use one, without any "magical keywords" (user can choose the operation (factorize, solve, expand,...) and enter the expression). My (14-18 years old) students language isn't english so similar CAS wouldn't be the best solution.

Comment: I thought Wolfram Alpha was relatively flexible with keywords, and they market saying you can write freely, with the software being very understanding.  You may want to try.

Comment: Yes, you've right, very impressive. But my students speaks english very poor (me too :) ), they don't know about mathematical (english) terminology (and sometimes don't know about hungarian terminology too). I've show http://mathics.net/ for them but would be nice a very simple, intuitiv, hungarian solution. Check http://uzsolt.hu/cas/ (and use google translator :) ).

Comment: Maxima will be good choice: TeX-support, factor working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your need, you could just make a simple package for something like SymPy or yacas. The package could just provide aliases (re-namings) to the functions you want them to use. So, they would just enter like

> Hfactorize(x^2-y^2)  %I don't know the Hungarian word for factorize

and it would spit back out something like

```
(x-y)(x+y)
```

Since all of the inputs and outputs are math, they don't need any translation. The only big issue I see with this strategy is that they wouldn't be able to interpret any error messages they got, unless they spoke English.

I'm not sure what the status of SymPy is for translations. It doesn't look like there's a Hungarian version, but there appear to be a few different European languages available.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I've created a simple web page where the user can choose a radiobutton to specify the operation. The PHP-script will generate the expression to yacas/maxima/etc so I don't want translate the function names.